# How to copy an Azure blob to an asset using the PHP sdk?

Tags: php, azure, assets, azure-blob-storage, azure-media-services

I am using this SDK: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php

I found some comments about "copyBlob" in the [issues page.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=copyBlob)

But I can't find anything in the actual [code.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=copyBlob)

I'd like to copy media files from a storage account to my media services account. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CopyBlob in the PHP SDK to copy blobs within the same account. If you are looking to copy to a different account, you will need to download and upload. Or alternatively you can use AzCopy to move files from one account to another.